# Restore failed for Server using SMO in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

im stack in this part of my TestProject.

```
Restore restore = new Restore();
restore.Database = "SIMSDB";
restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

string BAKlocation = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\Backup\\dbBAK.bak";
restore.Devices.AddDevice(BAKlocation, DeviceType.File);
restore.ReplaceDatabase = false;

RelocateFile file1 = new RelocateFile("SIMSDB", "D:\\backupdb\\SIMSDB.mdf");
RelocateFile file2 = new RelocateFile("SIMSDB_log", "D:\\backupdb\\SIMSDB_Log.ldf");
restore.RelocateFiles.Add(file1);
restore.RelocateFiles.Add(file2);

ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
srvConn.LoginSecure = true;
Server sqlServer = new Server(srvConn);
restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

the exception is

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Restore
>   failed for Server 'DENVER-PC\SQLEXPRESS'. --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An
>   exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The media family on device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\dbBAK.bak' is incorrectly
>   formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family. RESTORE DATABASE
>   is terminating abnormally. at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction
>   action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean
>   catchException) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   queries) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server
>   server, StringCollection queries) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)

by the way the bak file is from smarterasp.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98918/sql-server-2014-bak-file-error-the-media-family-on-device-d-is-incorrec

Comment: i dont have sql management studio

Comment: You can [get SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx), pretty essential for anyone working with SQL Server.

Comment: is there any other way to fix the problem i posted?